# Reuse model and store from ExtJS in Sencha Touch

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I already have an ExtJS app but now I'm trying to build a mobile version with Sencha Touch. I want the browser to detect if it's running on mobile or not. That works fine, but what is my next step?
I have it redirected to a /mobile folder with a new index.html and that works fine until I try to reach classes from a parent class.

Is it possible to load the mobile app.js instead of the extjs app.js in the primary index.html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you will be able to get away with having just one application. Ultimately you would need to create two different apps - one using ExtJs framework, another using Sencha Touch.

Whether you will be able to share some code is a good question. I think you should be able to share models, but that's about it. And even though - I would not recommend doing that either. Because even if show similar information from the same back end in both full and mobile version of your application, you might not need all of it in the mobile application. And if you don't need all of it - your models will be different.